# Cant figure out the error and resolution in PL SQL code

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have provided this code for fetching out all the table descriptions of all schemas in one database. I searched online and came up with the code below. I can't figure out the error.

Anyone who can either help with this error OR provide me an alternative to the problem

```
SQL>  Begin
  2    For q in (select distinct owner from dba_objects)
  3    loop
  4   for r in (select table_name, owner from all_tables where owner = 'q.owner')
  5   loop
  6    dbms_output.put_Line('table '||r.table_name);
  7    execute immediate 'desc ' || r.table_name
  8    end loop;
  9    end loop;
 10    end;
 11    /

end loop;
 *

ERROR at line 8:
ORA-06550: line 8, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
. ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
return returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk
member submultiset
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
```

Comment: Line 7 must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: thanks! let me try that ! appreciate the quick reply. Also do you think the code for my problem statement is going to work? the outer for loop makes a list of schemas for which the inner for loop works to fine table descriptions. I mean thats what i understand. do you concur?

Comment: Also take the quotes off of 'q.owner'.

Comment: Actually, you might as well just run a query against all_tab_columns to get this sort of result.

Comment: thanks david. do you mean for the inner or outer loop? could you provide me with the SQL please ?

Comment: There are many ways to get information about tables structure. This structure can be very complex (nested tables, object tables and so on). Therefore, please describe the purpose of getting such information (what you want to do with collected data) to provide appropriate way to collect data for you.        P.S.  Script is totally wrong, at least you can't `execute immediate`  `desc` command because it's an SQL*Plus command and not valid SQL statement.

Comment: thank you for that Thinkjet. Let me explain. SO we are doing some data masking activity. we need to 1. take data out of the tables 2. apply our masking utility and 3. put the masked data back Now, for that we are trying to analyze what would be candidate tables need to be masked for this activity. My DBA seems to be busy and non cooperative, so i took it upon myself to find him a script that 1. within 1 DB, looks for all Schema names and 2. fetches the "desc table" for each table within that schema. to handle the 2 points above, i found that code for which i was getting errors. I justneed desc

Comment: ...and also , could you elaborate on "totally wrong". not sure how to interpret that. 
also, if exec immediate isnt the right command, what could i write in its place that would have the same effect?? 
Thank you in advance Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select   *
from     all_tab_columns
where    owner = 'MY_OWNER_NAME'
order by owner,
         table_name,
         column_id;
```

Use the reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm) to select the column of interest to you. You can add other predicates if you're only interested in character data types, for example.

Comment: thats great david thanks! could i write it in that block of PLSQL as execute immediate "your select statement"?? if so how ? thankk you for bearing with my lack of PL SQL i really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You could just include it in a PL/SQL block as a regular cursor, but there should be no need to use PL/SQL at all. This can be executed straight from a SQL client such as SQL Developer or SQL*Plus

Answer (score 0):

Line 7: `execute immediate 'desc ' || r.table_name`

You forgot to put `;`